# How to close this menu clicking outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this menu:

CSS

```
#message { 
 display: none; 
 position: absolute; 
 width: 120px; 
 background: #fff; 
 color: #000; 
 font-weight: bold; 
}
```

When I click in  it opens #message.
My problem is to close this thing.

JS:

```
$(function() {

  $("#subm").click(function(evt) {
    $("#message").css({
      top: 55,
      left: evt.pageX - 55
    }).show();
  });

});
```

I try to put this code inside function above:

```
  $('html').click(function(evt) {
    if($('#message').is(":visible")) {
        $('#message').hide();
    }
  });
```

but nothing is happening, apparently menu is opening and closing in the same time.
What is wrong? how can I close this menu clicking outside message box or even in span class?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmpf1usu/3/)

Comment: It might be helpful if you explained what the desired behaviour is both in terms of how the `div` should be shown and hidden. I _assume_ there is a reason why you do not simply toggle the visibility using [`.toggle`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)...?

Comment: Can you explain the left movement done by css..., what are you goals with it

Comment: I have a span ellement, that when you click it will show message div, but I can't close this div after it opens. I just need to close it if I click outside that div or even in span with opens it. I don't know how to use toggle.

Comment: just open a menu when click in span. like stackoverflow when you click in that letter icon in top menu

Comment: well you've got now million of answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a click handler to the `document` to close it:

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/jmpf1usu/4/

```
  $("#subm").click(function(evt) {
    $("#message").css({
      top: 55,
      left: evt.pageX + 55
    }).show();

      evt.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(document).click(function(){
      $("#message").hide();
  });
```

`evt.stopPropagation()`is required so that the click never reaches the `document`, thus immediately triggering it to close again.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your js to this:

```
$("#subm").click(function() {
  $("#message").show();
 });

$("#message").mouseleave(function(){
   $("#message").hide(); 
});
```

When the user hits the button the menu will open. When the user mouse leaves the div it will hide it. Is that what you're looking for?

If you really want a click to remove the visibility you can do:

```
$("body").on('click',function(){
   $("#message").hide(); 
});
```

I just prefer the mouse leave, tbh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for hide message

```js
$(function() {
 

 
  $("#subm").click(function(evt) {
      
    $("#message").css({
   top: 55,
      left: evt.pageX + 55
    }).show();
  });
    $(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is("#subm")) {
        $("#message").hide();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
    #message { 
     display: none; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 120px; 
     background: red; 
     color: #fff; 
     font-weight: bold; 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="subm">open</span>

<div id="message">
message
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try with below code snippet.

```
$(function() { 
  $("#subm").click(function(evt) {
       evt.stopPropagation();
    $("#message").css({
      top: 55,
      left: evt.pageX + 55
    }).show();
  });


    $('html').click(function() {
        $("#message").hide();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmpf1usu/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.hide` to hide that element. Add an event listener for `#message` and do the following:

```
  $("#message").click(function(evt) {
     $("#message").hide();
  });
```

I put a working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jmpf1usu/8/

Comment: he want to click other element not the same element

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(function () {    
    $("#message").click(function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });
                     
    $("#subm").click(function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        $("#message").css({
            top: 55,
            left: evt.pageX + 55
        }).toggle();
    });

    $('html').click(function (evt) {
        if ($('#message').is(":visible")) {
            $('#message').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#message {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="subm">open</span>
<div id="message">message</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it without `stopPropagation()` shenanigans you can add the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(event) {         
        if(event.target.id != "message" 
            && event.target.id != "subm" 
            && $('#message').is(':visible')) 
            {            
                    $('#message').hide();

            }        
    });
 });
```

This is set up so that if the user clicks anything that is not the `#message` and is not the `#subm` open `span`, the message div will hide.

Expanded your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmpf1usu/10/

Good luck :).