# Click anywhere except element to close element

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm hoping someone can help me out with a jquery problem that is stumping me. I have a menu on the left side of the page that is opened and closed by jquery animations. I'm trying to write code that will also close the menu by clicking anywhere on the site except for the menu itself:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event){
  if((".menu").hasClass("menu--open")){
    if(!$(event.target).hasClass("menu")) {
      $(".menu").animate({width: 'toggle'});
      $(".menu").removeClass("menu--open");
    }
  }
}
```

Although jquery animations open and close the menu, I added a class toggle as well to distinguish whether or not the menu is open, otherwise clicking anywhere on the page will open it instead of just the menu button.

The animations seem to open and close the menu perfectly in other places (e.g. the menu button that toggles it), however in this instance, the only result I seem to get from the above code and many other tries is that not only does clicking anywhere off the menu NOT close it, but the dropdowns in the menu itself don't work either. Only the button that opens the menu still works.

I'd really appreciate any help with this! Thanks.

---

Latest code as per Taplar's suggestion:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event){
  if((".menu").hasClass("menu--open")){
    if($(event.target).closest(".menu").length == 0) {
      $(".menu").animate({width: 'toggle'});
      $(".menu").removeClass("menu--open");
    }
  }
}
```

The menu functions (dropdowns, etc) now work, but clicking outside the menu still doesn't close it.

---

Tried this (please correct me if I misunderstood your suggestion):

```
$(document).on('click', function(event){
  if((".menu").hasClass("menu--open")){
    console.log($(event.target).closest(".menu").length)
    if($(event.target).closest(".menu").length == 0) {
      $(".menu").animate({width: 'toggle'});
      $(".menu").removeClass("menu--open");
    }
  }
}
```

This solution doesn't change anything; it works the same as my previous edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close this menu clicking outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794096/how-to-close-this-menu-clicking-outside)

Comment: Out of curiosity, put `console.log($(event.target).closest(".menu").length)` right before your inner if and see what it prints out.

Comment: Edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(event.target).closest('.menu').length
```

You can use closest to go up through the dom tree to find the closest parent that matches a selector.  It can also match on itself.  So if you run that and the length is 0, you clicked on something not in the menu and not the menu itself.

Comment: I added `if(!$(event.target).closest("o-mainnav").length == 0)`  and that solved one problem; now the main menu functions like dropdowns will work when opened, but the menu still doesn't close by clicking anywhere.

What's stranger is that there is already code for an "anywhere-but-the-menu click event" which works perfectly, but it was written by someone who doesn't work here anymore. I'm adding my code to that function, so maybe that is part of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

your missing a '$' and a semi-colon - that's why your code doent work, wannere.